# How to insert the output of a pig script into hive external tables using a dynamically generated partition value?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql, hcatalog

I have written a pig script that would generate tuples of a hive table. I am trying to dump the results to a specific partition in HDFS where hive stores the table date. As of now the partition value I am using is a timestamp string value that is generated inside pigscript. I have to use this timestamp string value to store my pig script results but i am have no idea how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you read some data from a partition of a HIVE table and want to store into another HIVE table partitions, right?
A HIVI partition (form HDFS perspective) is just a subfolder which name is constructed like this: fieldname_the_partitioning_is_based_on=value
For example you have a date partition it looks like this: hdfs_to_your_hive_table/date=20160607/

So all you need is to specify this output location in the store statement

STORE mydata INTO '$HIVE_DB.$TABLE' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer('date=$today');